# Anaconda Navigator doesn't show up in Windows Search bar

Tags: python, anaconda3

I downloaded the Anaconda Distribution and followed all steps on the docs website. 
If I change my directory in Windows cmd prompt to C:---\Anaconda\Scripts and type "activate root", I can use the anaconda-navigator cmd to launch the navigator. However, I do not see any icon for the Anaconda Prompt if I type Anaconda in my search bar, and I would like to not launch the Navigator every single time by this "activate root" command. 
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-equivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux)?

Comment: Just watched it, but can't really understand it.